# convert datetime to timestamp php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

My GPS device is communicating to my php web services, it sends date=311011 and time=060904 formats.

```
    $time=str_split($time,2);
    $date=str_split($date,2);
    $time=implode(":",$time);
    $date=implode("-",$date);
```

This gives me the required date and time standard notations.

- date=31-10-11
- time=06:09:04

Now, i wanna convert this date, time to timestamp. I worked with strtotime(), but the date seems to be 31-10-11, which gives strange results. Do i have to append 20 to 11 statically to make it 2011, or any solution

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+datetime+to+timestamp+php

Comment: doing research before asking is not optional. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the [date fortmats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). if you use `-` as separator, php assumes it's `y-mm-dd`, but your order is `dd-mm-y`. the easiest way would be to change the separator to `.` wich would then be `dd.mm.y`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strptime()`

Specifically:  `strptime("$date $time", '%d%m%y %H%M%S');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php):

```
$p = strptime($date.$time, '%d%m%y%H%M%S');
$timestamp = mktime($p['tm_hour'], $p['tm_min'], $p['tm_sec'], $p['tm_mon'], $p['tm_mday'], $p['tm_year']);
```

Or the newer [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) variant:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($date.$time, 'dmyHis');
$timestamp = $dateTime->format('U');
```

Or just string manipulation together with [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) on such a regular format:

```
list($d, $m, $y, $h, $i, $s) = str_split($date.$time, 2);
$timestamp = mktime($h, $i, $s, $m, $d, $y);
```