# Using php convert string datetime to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with convert string datetime to timestamp in php.

```
$time = strtotime('2012-12-28 01:02:43');

echo $time; //it returns 1356627763
```

when I convert that integer value back to datetime it isn't correct (28/12/2012 00:02:43). Basically, it's late 1 hour.

```
my_format_datetime(strtotime('2012-12-28 01:02:43'));
```

Below is my my_format_datetime function :

```
> function my_format_datetime($unix)
>         {
>             if ($unix == '' || !is_numeric($unix))
>             {
>                     $unix = strtotime($unix);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 $timezone = 3600*(DEFAULT_GMT + date("0"));
>                 $unix = gmdate("d/m/Y H:i:s", $unix + $timezone);
>             }
>             
>             return $unix;
>         }
```

But when I convert using time() function it's correct.

Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: what is the value to `DEFAULT_GMT`

Comment: `$timezone = 3600*(DEFAULT_GMT + date("0"));` My guess would be the issue is with this.

Comment: Try this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950854/convert-datetime-to-timestamp-php

Comment: DEFAULT_GMT is the timezone value (Exp: for my location is 7)

Answer (score 1):

Set your local time zone.
You can do it in php script by using `date_default_timezone_set()` .http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

or you can do it in `php.ini` configuration by changing the `date.timezone` value which defaults to UTC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've mistaken timezone between local and global time.